# Binding dependency property in extended textbox to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have extended the functionality of a textbox, below is part of the class with an attached property RegularExpressionEnabled:

```
public class AlphaNumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    #region DependencyProperties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegularExpressionEnabledProperty =
                                                    DependencyProperty.Register("RegularExpressionEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(AlphaNumericTextBox),
                                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool RegularExpressionEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(RegularExpressionEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RegularExpressionEnabledProperty, value); Console.WriteLine("RegularExpressionEnabled:" + (bool)value); }
    }
```

}

This class is then incorporated into a UserControl.
XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Libs_ViewLevel.Controls.FilterItemControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Libs_ViewLevel" 
             xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:Libs_ViewLevel.Controls"
             x:Name="UserControl">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="Auto" >
        <ctrls:AlphaNumericTextBox x:Name="AlphaNumericTbx"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Text="{Binding AlphaNumericValue}"
                                   RegularExpressionEnabled="{Binding RegExpressionEnabled}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class FilterItemControl : UserControl
{
    public FilterItemControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public bool RegExpressionEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(RegExpressionEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RegExpressionEnabledProperty, value); Console.WriteLine("RegExpressionEnabled:" + (bool)value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegExpressionEnabledProperty =
                                                    DependencyProperty.Register("RegExpressionEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(FilterItemControl),
                                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

I have placed the UserControl in a Window and in the code-behind of this window, placed this statement: `txtbox.RegExpressionEnabled = true;`

In both RegularExpressionEnabled and RegExpressionEnabled you can see that I have placed a Console.Write().

The RegExpressionEnabled prints to the Output screen, however it does not get to the second, RegularExpressionEnabled.

Something is wrong in my binding on AlphaNumericTextBox `RegularExpressionEnabled="{Binding RegExpressionEnabled}"`, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: hm.. could it be `BindsTwoWayBeDefault`? It is passed as a parameter to `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`. Not sure, so posting as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: When you bind your `RegularExpressionEnabled` property, WPF does not call the CLR wrapper (where you've put the console output) when the source property has changed. Instead it directly calls `SetValue`. See the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) article on MSDN for details. In order to get notified about changes of a depedency property value, you would have to register a PropertyChangedCallback with the property's metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code behind of FilterItemControl, RegExpressionEnabled property should be a standard property as this is what your new textbox is binding to.  You don't need the dependency property in the FilterItemControl code behind either as you already have it in the new textbox.

Now instead of setting txtbox.RegExpressionEnabled = true (which actually should be txtbox.RegularExpressionEnabled = true), you set the RegExpressionEnabled property to true and the textbox will bind to this.

You will also need to raise the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the RegExpressionEnabled property to trigger the databinding.

Comment: I changed the FilterItemControl RegExpressionEnabled to a normal property with a PropertyChanged event, in which I get and set AlphaNumericTbx.RegularExpressionEnabled. I removed the lines which had the binding in the XAML. Works nicely thanks